# How to set the logoff with the password is wrong in textbox?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

```
 Public Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal dwOptions As Long, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
 
 
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox2 <> "123" Then
 ExitWindowsEx 4, 0 'log off
 
Else
   ExitWindowsEx 1, 0  'shut down 
End Sub
```

I just reference to this

http://officetricks.com/logoff-or-shutdown-computer-with-excel/

## Error

**Fixed-length strings not allowed as the type of a public member of an object module; private object modules not allowed as the type of a public member of a public object module**

Comment: If the error is occurring on the lines saying `ExitWindowsEx 4, 0 //log off` and `ExitWindowsEx 1, 0  //shut down` then it is because `//` is not valid in VBA.  If your error is something else, you will need to tell us what it is.

Comment: @YowE3K   I didn't use` //` in my code . The error msg  is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep that's still a compile error:

[image]

The message is a bit cryptic, but what it's saying is that you can't put a **public** WinAPI function (e.g., `Public Declare Function...`) in a UserForm or Class Module. You can get around this by declaring it as `Private`:

```
Private Declare Function ExitWindowsEx Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal dwOptions As Long, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
```

Or, you can put it in a standard code module and keep it `Public` which will allow it to be accessible from other modules, classes, forms, etc.

[image]

Comment: I fix this .Then ,`ExitWindowsEx` is not defined .How to solve